# Check ImageField without form

Tags: python, django

Novice Django question. I have an ImageField on a Model, to which I am uploading files. The uploading works fine, except I'm not getting ValidationErrors when I upload a file that's not an image. This is obviously bad for security. full_clean is working great for my URLField and EmailField, but not for ImageField.

A summary of what's in my model:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    home = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=uploader, blank=True, null=True)
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(Thing, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

A summary of what's happening in my view and my test:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.test.client import Client

#In views.py
#This is the view for the URL things/[id]
#Modifies an existing model to upload an image to it

def thing(request, thing_id):
    try:
        thing = Thing.objects.get(pk=int(thing_id))
    except:
        raise Http404
    if request.method == 'POST':
        thing.image = request.FILES.get('image')
        try:
            thing.save()
        except ValidationError as e:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Error message here")
        return HttpResponse(status=201)



#In tests.py
#This should not work; 'tests.py' is not an image

with open('myapp/tests.py') as f:
    response = Client().post('/things/1', {'image': f})
    print response.content, response.status_code

    #I get that the HTTP status code = 201, not = 400.
```

I have found plenty of information about how to do this with a Form, but I don't want to have to use one. I am creating a REST API / web service and don't have a need to embed forms in templates anywhere, so forms seem like unnecessary work.

[Django ImageField validation (is it sufficient)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770660/django-imagefield-validation-is-it-sufficient) covers how ImageField validation works, but not how I implement it.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: I think calling the save method just saves the model instance, but it does not validate before saving. You have to call model.full_clean(). Have a look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Comment: In the code, I overrode model.save() to call full_clean(). And full_clean() is working properly for the URLField and EmailField -- it throws a ValidationError when I enter something that's not an email, for example. Just not for ImageField. Thanks though.

Comment: ooops, havent seen that...

Comment: Results of additional science: Thinking that the "blank=True, null=True" might be to blame, I added "blank=True, null=True" to my URLField and it still threw ValidationError when the input was an incorrect URL.