# Django models.ImageField does not validate image file (data sent by axios)

Tags: django, reactjs, imagefield

I'm using Django as my backend and React as my front.
I want the users to be able to upload their photos, and I managed to do that recently.

This is how the users send their photo in the front.

```
addUserImage = (Image, id) => (dispatch) => {
  axios.post(`/api/${id}/image`, Image, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); alert('Your image file is not valid. Please check again.'); });
};

onChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files.length !== 0) {
      if (e.target.files[0].size > 50000000) {
        alert(`'${e.target.files[0].name}' is too large, please pick a smaller file`);
      } else {
        this.setState({ selectedImage: e.target.files[0] }, () => {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append(
            'Image',
            this.state.selectedImage,
          );
          //this.props.onUploadPhoto calls addUserImage from above.
          this.props.onUploadPhoto(formData, this.props.selected_object.id);
        });
      }
    }
  }

<Button
        variant="contained"
        component="label"
      >
        <input
          type="file"
          id="image"
          accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/gif"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
        />
        Upload An Image!
      </Button>
```

This code manages to show normal images successfully. However, I'm worried that some users might just upload fake image files(e.g. Forcefully changed extensions). I heard that Django's models.ImageField performs image validation. This is my related backend code.

```
//views.py
def post_photo(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                req_data = request.FILES['Image']
            except (KeyError, ValueError):
                return HttpResponseBadRequest()
            //Django should send a error here, but it doesn't : (
            image_instance = Image(filename=_get_file_id(), content=req_data, user=request.user)
            image_instance.save()
            ......

 //models.py
class Image(models.Model):
    """Model implementation of Image Model"""
    filename = models.TextField(max_length=128)
    content = models.ImageField(upload_to="image/", default="image/default_image.png")
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
    )
```

However, even if I post a fake image file, Django decides to store it in its ImageField. Is there a reason behind this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the file extension of your *fake image*?

Comment: it was an obj file named as a png file

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770660/django-imagefield-validation-is-it-sufficient

Comment: The PIL package is responsible for validating the data, ***if you are uploading through form***, and you are not doing so

Comment: I thought my case was different cause I'm not using form. I guess it's mandatory if I want to use validation. Thanks a lot!